# How to get current window mode in glut?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to get the glut window mode.

Is there a built-in function that returns if the glut window is in full screen mode or not?

Comment: Normally you'd have a global boolean that keeps track.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) extensions (`freeglut.h` instead of `glut.h`) you can pass `GLUT_FULL_SCREEN` to `glutGet()`:

```
bool isFullscreen = ( 1 == glutGet( GLUT_FULL_SCREEN ) );
```